# Python script won't run using PHP

Tags: python, php, adafruit

I'm using a Raspberry Pi as a server and have a simple python script that uses the Adafruit PCA9685 library, when I run the python script using the terminal it works as expected however when I run the script from a php file it won't run.

This is the python script, when I run the php file I see "test1" in browser so I know the file is running but I don't see "test2" unless I remove the line before it so it's getting stuck when it tries to use the library.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from __future__ import division
import sys
import os
import json
import time
import Adafruit_PCA9685

print("test1")
# Initialise the PCA9685 using the default address (0x40).
pwm = Adafruit_PCA9685.PCA9685()

print("test2")

# Set frequency to 60hz, good for servos.
pwm.set_pwm_freq(800)

# print('Moving servo on channel 0, press Ctrl-C to quit...')
while True:
    # Move servo on channel O between extremes.
    print("test3")
    pwm.set_pwm(15, 0, 1)
    time.sleep(1)
    pwm.set_pwm(15, 0, 20)
    time.sleep(1)
```

This is the php file.

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("python3 /var/www/html/python/test.py");
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: _"when I run the php file I see "test1" in browser so I know the file is running"_ - That contradicts both the title and some of the text in your question where you say the file _doesn't_ run.

Comment: I couldn't come up with a better title without a paragraph, that's my problem for searching. It seems odd because the file is running so why doesn't it complete? Works in the terminal so why would it be any different as it's still running on the same server.

Comment: Why not just configure the webserver to be able to run python directly? Then you won't need PHP as an intermediary

Comment: I'm trying to control the PCA9685 from a web page, when a button is pressed I want action. :)

Comment: Yes. That's my point. The page could send the request directly to a URL which triggers a python script instead of a PHP script. Python can be used as server side script just like PHP can. No need to have PHP in the middle. Which webserver are you using?

Comment: Ok, so instead of using ajax to run the php file it would be the python file? I did see some examples like that, when I try it and print results to debug console it prints the exact file like I was viewing it in my editor, same when I load the python file in a browser, just shows all text in the file but doesn't execute anything. I'm running Apache 2 on a Raspberry Pi 3. All my testing is done on the local network if that matters.

Comment: Yes, that happens because you haven't configured Apache to execute python files as code. As I explained earlier, you can do this but you need to set it up first. https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+python&oq=apache+pyth&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l3.5179j0j7&client=ms-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Ah, ok, I just assumed because I could run python on Pi it was ready to go. I have Apache, PHP, MySQL and python installed so figured it was good but I didn't do anything to configure Apache with python, I don't think. Thanks a lot, I will search in this direction.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you again @ADyson I setup the apache2.conf file and I'm in business. :) No PHP either. ;)

Comment: Great, glad I was able to help